# Apache Spark and Scala required jars

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala.
Can any one suggest me what are the jar files required for running Apache Spark with Scala in Linux environment.Below code was a piece of original code. I am getting exceptions like  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorkerPool.(Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;I)V

java -cp ".:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.1-1.cdh5.7.1.p1876.1944/jars/*:./*"

TestAll.scala

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import java.io._
import java.sql.{Connection,DriverManager}
import scala.collection._
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
object TestAll {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf =new SparkConf().setAppName("Testing App").setMaster("local")
    val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
      println("Hello, world!")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a quick [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to ask good question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Spark from [here](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html). Choose the "Pre-built with Hadoop" option. Then you can follow the directions of the [Quick Start](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html). This will get you through the Hello World. I am not sure which IDE you are using, but the most friendly for Scala is Intellij IDEA

Comment: You can download Spark using wget